# for linux How set icon on the title bar of a stage in java fx 1.8.45 of my application

Tags: javafx-8

I have tried the

```
new Image(XYZ.class.getResourceAsStream("my.png"))
```

and

```
stage.getIcons().add(new Image("my.jpg"));
```

and 
  `stage.getIcons().add(new Image("/path/to/my.jpg"));`

i can see icon at task bar but i can not see at app title bar
my javafx jar version is 1.8.45
thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following, this worked for me:

```
Image image = new Image(XYZ.class.getClassLoader().getResource("my.png").toExternalForm());
stage.getIcons().add(image);
```

If you're using Linux, you may be interested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26039593/icon-set-for-javafx-application-is-visible-in-windows-but-not-in-ubuntu).

Here is a MWE:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.getIcons().add(new Image(Main.class.getClassLoader().getResource("sample/icon.png").toExternalForm()));
        stage.setScene(new Scene(new Group(), 300, 275));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {launch(args);}
}
```

This assumes that there is an image `icon.png` in directory `sample` (which is the same directory as the `Main` class). As you can see, the icon is both in the task bar and in the title bar of the application:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thank you for replay but this is not working and giving java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: The NPE is most likely caused by a wrong path to the image. Make sure to set the full path like the last example in your post.

Comment: my image is visible in task bar of my app but not showing at title bar

Comment: Do you mean the MWE is not working for you? This is the result on my end: http://i.stack.imgur.com/yuK5O.png

Comment: i found the problem i using Linux in linux that is not working in windows its working beautifully Thx so much

Comment: In that case, it may be because of the dimensions of the icon, take a look at the link i edited in, maybe it helps you :)