# JavaFX 8 application does not show its application icon

Tags: eclipse, debian, javafx-8

I am trying to set an icon to my JavaFX 8 Application, but the icon is not shown.
Trying to understand the problem I create a very simple application with one Main class.
Here is its code:

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        StageStyle style = primaryStage.getStyle();
        // style == StageStile.DECORATED

        try {
            primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("phog16.png"))); // iconSize == 16x16px
            primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("phog22.png"))); // iconSize == 22x22px
            primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("phog24.png"))); // ...
            primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("phog32.png")));
            primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("phog48.png")));
            primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("phog16.png")));
            primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("phog64.png")));
            primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("phog128.png")));
            primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("phog256.png")));
            primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("phog512.png")));

            int size = primaryStage.getIcons().size();
            // size == 10

            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.setTitle("Application Icon");

            primaryStage.show();
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

As application output shows there is no application icon:
[application output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCTS7.png)

My environment:
Debian 9.1 (Stretch) 64bit Gnome; 
eclipse-SDK-4.7-linux-gtk-x86_64; 
jdk-8u144-linux-x64

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Stupid question (as I'm not aware of Gnome-specific behaviour): does other application show some icon?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ICON set for JavaFX application is visible in Windows but not in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26039593/icon-set-for-javafx-application-is-visible-in-windows-but-not-in-ubuntu)